# View files on a Raspbian SD Card from a Mac?

Tags: raspbian, sd-card, partition, file

Recently, my Pi 3 broke, and I had some important files on its Raspbian Stretch SD card. I would like to get these files off the SD card without buying a whole new Pi. 
Does anyone know a way of doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Just plug it into your computer. It doesn't work?

Comment: All I get is the Boot partition. The files I need are on a seperate  EXT4 partition that I can't access from my Mac.

Comment: Try `ls /dev` can you see new device here? I am not sure about names on Mac but on linux SD card is `mmcblkxxx`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To view files from your `EXT4` partition you'll need to download [FUSE for macOS](https://osxfuse.github.io/). This solution only lets you read, not write, but this should be enough to recover your files.

```
brew cask install osxfuse
brew install ext4fuse
```

Create a directory where you want to mount the `EXT4` partition. I'll just call it `mnt`. Navigate to the directory containing `mnt` and type (including the quotation marks)

```
sudo ext4fuse "/dev/disk2s2" "mnt/" -o allow_other
```

In my case, the micro SD card is under `/dev/disk2` and the `EXT4` partition corresponds to `disk2s2`. To make sure which is your partition, type `diskutil list`.

Then you can `cd` into `mnt/` and recover your files, for example by issuing the `dd` command and saving a copy on your Mac. Let me know if this works, and if you're facing any issues related to `FUSE`.

To unmount the partition

```
sudo umount mnt
```

**References**

[Mount EXT4 partitions on macOS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/210198/mount-ext4-on-el-capitan)

[ext4fuse mount-point disappearing](https://github.com/gerard/ext4fuse/issues/32)

Comment: Two issues (with homebrew anyway): `osxfuse has been succeeded by macfuse as of version 4.0.0` and `ext4fuse has been disabled because it requires closed-source macFUSE`

Answer (score 2):

`macOS` can't (actually won't) show Linux `ext4` partitions. There used to be 3rd party software to mount these, but Apple are making it more difficult with each new release, and AFAIK it is not possible with SIP.

You can see the contents on any Linux OS - this can be a virtual machine, a bootable image or another Pi.

I find a Pi with a fresh Raspbian installation and SD Card reader the easiest.

See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/95156/8697

Answer (score 0):

One way is to boot a live Linux CD on your Mac.

I do not have a Mac so can't vouch for the following instructions.

https://www.howtogeek.com/213396/how-to-boot-a-linux-live-usb-drive-on-your-mac/

Once Linux is booted it will be able to see the file systems on the SD card (FAT for the boot partition, and ext4 for the rest).